# Removing pointer from tooltip in amcharts 4

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Is it possible to remove pointer on tooltip in amCharts?

I know you can change orientation by setting

```
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation
```

to one of the following

`"horizontal" | "vertical" | "left" | "right" | "up" | "down"`

but is it possible to remove it completley?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointer is part of the tooltip `background`, which is a [pointed rectangle](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/pointedrectangle/). Its length can be set with the property `pointerLength`. So I would try to set the length to 0:

```
series.tooltip.background.pointerLength = 0;
```